Configuring Oracle Apex on premise to Oracle BI Publisher
I'm currently working on implementing a web application using Oracle APEX on-premise. However, I'm encountering significant difficulties in configuring Oracle APEX with Oracle BI Publisher.
I followed the steps outlined in this video (https://youtu.be/QFiGqcblN6w?si=4xs8Zg32deSfefF7), but nothing seems to be working correctly. I still can't access BI reports from my APEX application.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, could you please share some solutions or advice?
Thank you!

Did you check with Oracle support ?

I solved this problem :">
